# Are Monomorphisms injective?

Tags: schemes, monomorphisms, morphism

In the categories of topological spaces, rings, groups and sets I know that a morphism is a monomorphism iff it's injective.

Things are different for schemes. In fact I know that a scheme injective morphism isn't in general a monomorphism (and I have some counter examples), but I don't know whether the converse is true of false.

> A monomorphism between schemes is injective?

Answer (score 5):

By default, an injective morphism of schemes is an injective map of the underlying topological spaces.

A morphism of schemes $f:X\to Y$ is a monomorphism if and only if the diagonal morphism $\Delta_{X/Y}:X\to X\times_Y X$ is an isomorphism, see [Tag 01L3](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01L3).

A morphism of schemes $f:X\to Y$ is universally injective if and only if the diagonal morphism $\Delta_{X/Y}:X\to X\times_Y X$ is surjective, see [Tag 01S4](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01S4).

So we have

$\ \ \ \ $[$f$ is a monomorphism]

$\Leftrightarrow$[$\Delta_f$ is isomorphic]

$\Rightarrow$[$\Delta_f$ is surjective]

$\Leftrightarrow$[$f$ is universally injective]

$\Rightarrow$[$f$ is injective]

So the answer is yes, any monomorphism of schemes is injective.

Answer (score 0):

a quick google search for "monomorphisms of schemes" yields this nice post:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/56591/what-are-the-monomorphisms-in-the-category-of-schemes

Condition (c) at least answers your question in the positive for morphisms locally of finite type.

For arbitrary affine schemes note that a monomorphism of Spec's corresponds to an epimorphism (ie, surjection) of rings. For a surjection of rings, it's clear that the induced maps on spec (by taking preimages of primes) must be injective. Here you don't need the LoFT condition.

Passing to arbitrary schemes and arbitrary monomorphisms would probably require a more subtle analysis. A general technique in this area is essentially using the idea that any morphism of schemes is an inverse limit of LoFT morphisms (this might not quite be correct - I don't have a precise statement).

Comment: Here I intended "injective" in the category of scheme, that is having kernel zero

Comment: @Exodd How do you define the kernel of a morphism of schemes?

Comment: @Exodd also "injective" is not a category-theoretic term. It's a set-theoretic term, so injectivity only makes sense for functions between sets. There are a number of ways to associate a set to a scheme, but the default is to take its underlying topological space.

Comment: ok, sorry for using injective in an improper way, but I thought that for schemes (and sheafs in general) it meant that $f:X\to Y$ is injective iff $\mathcal O_Y(U)\to \mathcal O_X(f^{-1}(U))$ are injective for all open set $U$

Comment: @Exodd That's a completely different condition, for which the answer to your question would be almost never. The sheaf is in many ways dual to the scheme, so monomorphisms of schemes may often correspond to epimorphisms of sheaves and monomorphisms of sheaves may often correspond to epimorphisms of schemes. Take the affine case here there is a duality between affine schemes and their coordinate rings. Thus monomorphisms of schemes correspond to epimorphisms of rings. The rings here are basically the same as the sheaf on the affine scheme.

Comment: @Exodd Perhaps you could recall the definition of a closed immersion (which is a monomorphism of schemes which thought of as being "especially nice"). The definition requires that a closed immersion induce a *surjection* on sheaves.

Comment: @Exodd You should think of the sheaf on a scheme $X$ as playing the role of packaging the collection of "functions on open subsets of $X$" into one object. Often in geometry/topology, given a space you can define a natural sheaf of functions on it. Conversely, it's often possible, given a sheaf of functions, to recover the space itself. In algebraic geometry this "duality" only strictly exists for affine schemes (and certain other restricted situations), which is why in general we define a scheme to be a space *together* with a sheaf whose sections over U should be thought of as functions on U

Comment: localizations are epimorphisms of rings which aren't surjections on underlying sets.