# Does Spec send all ring epimorphisms to injective maps?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

We know that the Spec construction, without the structure sheaf and Zariski topology, gives a functor $\mathrm{CommRings}^{\mathrm{op}}\rightarrow \mathrm{Set}$, and furthermore
this functor sends (the opposite arrows of) the following kinds of ring homomorphisms to injective maps in Set:

- surjective ring homomorphisms (quotients by ideals); and
- localizations (at multiplicative subsets).

Both of these are examples of ring epimorphisms.
I was wondering, in general does $\mathrm{Spec}$ send all ring epimorphisms to injective maps?

Comment: Yes. $\text{Spec}$ is an antiequivalence of categories, so monos of affine schemes are epis of rings. But it's "well known" that a mono of schemes must be injective, in particular this is true for affine schemes. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1394904/are-monomorphisms-injective), say. This is a bit overkill, since that result almost certainly relies on the result you're asking about, but it's a quick way to see it's true. This has probably been asked before, and I'll spend a couple minutes trying to find a duplicate. If I can't, I'll write up an answer in a little while

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Thanks for your explanation! May I also ask: do monomorphisms of (affine or general?) schemes give topological embeddings on the underlying topological spaces?

Comment: A monomorphism in $\mathsf{Top}$ is just an injective continuous function, so certainly a mono of schemes is also a mono of underlying spaces. However, you're asking the wrong question: a mono in $\mathsf{Top}$ may not be an embedding. Instead, embeddings are the _regular_ monomorphisms in $\mathsf{Top}$. It's not obvious to me if regular monos of schemes always give regular monos on underlying topological spaces or not, and it's probably worth asking this as a separate question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand\ideal\mathfrak\newcommand\Spec{\operatorname{Spec}}$
Let $\varrho:A\to B$ be an epimorphism of commutative rings.
If $\varrho$ is surjective or a localization, then for every ideal $\ideal b\subseteq B$ we have $\ideal b=\varrho[\varrho^{-1}[\ideal b]]B$, hence $\Spec(\varrho)$ is injective.
In the general case, let $\ideal p\in\Spec(A)$ and consider the following commutative diagram of ring homomorphisms:

[image]

Since $\varrho_{\ideal p}$ is an epimorphism of commutative rings, $\psi$ is an epimorphism as well.
Since $A_{\ideal p}/\ideal pA_{\ideal p}$ is a field, $\psi$ is surjective.
Consequently, $B_{\ideal p}/\ideal pB_{\ideal p}$ has at most a prime ideal.
The following commutative diagram of pullback squares

[image]

shows $\Spec(\varrho)^{-1}[\{\ideal p\}]\cong\Spec(B_{\ideal p}/\ideal pB_{\ideal p})$.