# Showing that two schemes have homeomorphic topological spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two schemes over a base field $k$, and let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism of schemes. I was wondering if the following condition is sufficient for $f$ to be a homeomorphism between the topological spaces of $X$ and $Y$

> For every field extension $E/k$ we have $f(E): X(E) \to Y(E)$ is bijective.

More generally, what kind of information (if any) does the set $X(E)$ of $E$-points of $X$ give about the topological space of $X$?

Comment: What does the equality X(E) = Y(E) of sets mean for you? Just an arbitrary bijection between the E-points?

Comment: @CraniumClamp Thank you for your comment, I edited my question.

Comment: If the schemes $X$ and $Y$ have the property that the residue field at every point is $k$ (this is a quite atypical property), your hypothesis simply becomes: $f$ is a bijection. We can get a counter-example by adapting a standard example that a continuous bijection need not be a homeomorphism. Namely, consider $k[[x]]\rightarrow k\times k((x))$ that's projection to the quotient in the first and inclusions into the fraction field in the second factor. The map $\mathrm{Spec}(k\times k((x)))\rightarrow\mathrm{Spec}(k[[x]])$ is from a discrete two-point space to the Sierpinski space.

Comment: @Thorgott Do I still have any hope if $X$ and $Y$ were (locally) of finite type?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure.

Comment: @Thorgott could you please explain why $X$ and $Y$ having $k$ as residue field at every point implies that $f$ is bijective? I thought that $f(S):X(S) \to Y(S)$ should be bijective for all schemes $S$ over $k$ for $f$ to be bijective.

Comment: I'm not saying that every residue field being $k$ implies that $f$ is bijective. I'm saying that if the residue field at every point is $k$, then $f$ is bijective if and only if $f(E)$ is bijective for all field extensions $E/k$.

Comment: @Thorgott could you please explain this last equivalence you mention?

Comment: To say that every residue field is $k$ is to say that $X=X(E)$ resp. $Y=Y(E)$ for all field extensions $E/k$ (naturally wrt $f=f(E)$, of course).

Answer (score 1):

What you lack is integrality.

Firstly, let me show that your criterion implies that $f$ is universally injective and bijective:

It is clear that your condition implies that $f$ is surjective, thus universally surjective by [01S1](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01S1).
Your condition also implies that $f$ is injective on points and a point on $X$ has the same residue field as its image in $Y$. Thus by [01L6](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01L6), we know that $f$ is a monomorphism, in particular, $f$ is universally injective, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1394904/are-monomorphisms-injective).

Now [04DF](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04DF) shows that universal homeomorphism is equivalent to integral and universally injective and bijective.

You also asked about what if $f$ is of finite type.
Integral and locally of finite type implies finite [01WJ](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01WJ).
So to find an $f$ that satisfies your condition but not a homeomorphism, you should look for non-finite morphisms.
Indeed, there are a lot of them: for example, take $0\coprod \mathbb{G}_m\to \mathbb{A}^1.$